# An extender for the toggle button

Tags: switches, ups

I purchased a UPS board.  As you can see from the attached image there is an on/off slider switch.  I will be putting this kit inside a case. I want to let my customer move this switch, but it is quite small/fiddly. Would you know of any extension I could use please?

[image]

Comment: is there any way to use an external switch in series with the slide switch?

Comment: @jsotola Hi.  Well that is what I am looking for.

Comment: you have to figure out if the switch is connected as SPST or SPDT ... if SPST, then you can simply leave it in annopen position, and bridge the switch with another switch ... if it is SPDT, then you would have to remove the metal clip and remove the slider before bridging the switch with another

Comment: @jsotola thank u v much.  I will do some R&D :)

Comment: what is the purpose of the white connector? and the yellow one?

Answer (score 2):

That is a slide switch, rather than a toggle switch.

It may be possible to design something to operate that switch from outside the case, but I would probably remove that switch, and run wires from the pads it is soldered to out to a panel-mounted toggle switch.

Comment: I shall adjust my wording - thanks.  Yes, that is one of my options but I wanted an easier route to that.